# Parsing anchor tag with html-react-parser

Tags: reactjs, tsx

Couldn't find much about "html-react-parser" on here, so I have the following question, I'm trying to parse some html, but not sure what to put between anchor tags to get the link to show up, right now the links parse just fine except they don't show up in dom, they are invisible, I tried <a {...props}>{domNode.children[0].data} but it says that data Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'.

```
export const htmlParse = {
    replace: (domNode: DOMNode) => {
  
      if (domNode.type === 'tag' && domNode instanceof Element && domNode.name === 'a') {
  
        const props = attributesToProps(domNode.attribs)
  
        props.target = "_blank"
        props.rel = "noopener noreferrer nofollow" 
  
        // eslint-disable-next-line 
        return <a {...props}>{}</a>
      }
  
      return domNode
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I stuck with the exact same issue since last night and was struggling with it whole night. I ended up your post as well, before I found this, just now:

https://lightrun.com/answers/remarkablemark-html-react-parser-how-get-acces-to-children-data-property-with-typescript

Solution is: (domNode.children[0] as Text).data